# GetWebResourceUrl. Cant get embedded resource url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying get embedded image resource url via GetWebResourceUrl.

The situation:

Write Visual Studio package (extension). On click my menu button, i want to copy all embedded resource that located in `AssemblyName1`. At resource type `text/css` i have such url:

```
background-image: url('<%=WebResource("PSK.Web.UI.Controls.PSKSoftApp.Css.AppHeader.sprite.png")%>');
```

when copy such resource i want precompile it via WebResource, transform it to:

```
background-image: url('/WebResource.axd?d=PhPk80h_UWEcbheb-NHNP5WshV_47UOpWqAOl1_li
UFfN4cNofL74cFlQ1fvpFSf0&t=632573240669964903')
```

I hooked assembly (`AssemblyName1`) to my `VSPackage` assembly.
In `AssemblyName1`:

```
[assembly: WebResource("PSK.Web.UI.Controls.PSKSoftApp.Css.AppHeader.sprite.png", "image/png")]
```

`PSK.Web.UI.Controls.PSKSoftApp.Css.AppHeader.sprite.png` add to embedded resource.

In VSPackage assembly i write:

```
System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] methodCandidates = typeof(System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader).GetMember("GetWebResourceUrlInternal", 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);

foreach (var methodCandidate in methodCandidates)
{
    var method = methodCandidate as System.Reflection.MethodInfo;

    if (method == null || method.GetParameters().Length != 5) continue;

    object result = method.Invoke(null,
                                  new object[] 
                                  {
                                      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(PSK.Web.UI.Controls.PSKSoftApp.PSKSoftApp)),
                                      "PSK.Web.UI.Controls.PSKSoftApp.Css.AppHeader.sprite.png", 
                                      false, 
                                      false,
                                      null
                                  });
}
```

Calling

```
method.Invoke(null, new object[] {System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(PSK.Web.UI.Controls.PSKSoftApp.PSKSoftApp)),
                                      "PSK.Web.UI.Controls.PSKSoftApp.Css.AppHeader.sprite.png", false, false, null});
```

returns exception: `{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: basepath"}`

What is this **BasePath** and where should i set this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the top comment on google and I couldn't find a relevant answer, here is what I found to be the cause and solution (for me):

Situation:  trying to unit test some public methods on a server control I built that included a request to a WebResource.

Error:  "basepath" is null

Cause:  The control asks the page for a WebResource.  The Page asks for a ScriptManager to request said resource.  The ScriptManager does some internal stuff and tries to ask for the WebResource but hits a problem with "basepath".

Since this is a unit test, there is no web server.  No web server means the script manager doesn't know it's "basepath" for which to make a request.  No "basepath" means it has no way to construct the HTTP request for said resource.

Solution(s):  Two options:

A) Emulate/inject a web server in your unit tests to allow the Page/ScriptManager to generate a BasePath and make the appropriate requests.  There are resources for this online, but the best one I found (but did not use) referenced the use of the [AspNetDevelopmentServer] attribute.  I did not use this solution because we have a continuous integration build server and I did not want to screw around with getting the tests to work on all developer machines as well as the build server.  It might be easy, but I did not attempt it.

B) Re-design the control to make the webresource request in an non-testable (without effort) part of the server control.  I was using CreateChildControls (called automatically) and moved the webresource request to OnInit instead. Might not be best practice but it works for me.